# How can I make .one() event refresh without page reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used `el.one('click', fn)` in my codes. Now I need to refresh `.one()` event. I mean I want to call `fn` several times per clicking on `el` in the same loaded page.

I know, there is `.on()` event which sounds good in my case. But not really, I need `.one()` in general. Just few times I need to force `.one()` to acts like `.on()`.

Ok well, is there any solution?

Comment: If you want `on()`, don't call `one()`.

Comment: @SLaks I need `.one()` in the most of times .. Just few times I need to change the reaction of clicking on `el`.

Comment: yeah, rebind it. otherwise, no. you seem to already know the answer.

Comment: @stack You can use `.on` for your use case. Just `return` if you want it to behave as `.one` based on a condition.

Comment: you should describe you use case, than we can give you better help.

Comment: @Sushanth-- hmm, sounds good idea ..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn on `.on()` for as long as you need it to perform that way, and then do `.off()` to turn it back off.

Example:

```
var aFunc = function() { console.log('click!'); };

$("#foo").one("click", aFunc);

// some other stuff happens and when you need it...

$("#foo").on("click", aFunc);

// now you don't want it anymore

$("#foo").off("click", aFunc);
```

This is completely untested, but I think it might work.

It's important to note that to turn a handler `.off()`, you can't supply an anonymous function to `.on()`, that's why the function variable.